# Insert dropdown inside input field

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am having a hard time with this. There seems to be quite a few grotty ways of achieving this, but I would really like to find one which is less of a hack. I am after an input which also contains a dividing section on the left which has a dropdown.

This is basically what I am after:
http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/7BgYU/

```
<form name="multisearch" action="http://www.wittysparks.com/searchvideos/?q=" id="multisearchForm" method="get">
<ul class="ws_drop_down">
    <li><a href="#" title="Global Search"><span id="selectedsearch">ViDEOs</span>
    <![if gt IE 6]>
    </a>
    <![endif]>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
    <ul class='ws_drop_downm'>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="forWebSearch('http://www.wittysparks.com/news/search/?q=','NEWs');" title="Search NEWs">NEWs</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="forWebSearch('http://www.wittysparks.com/searchvideos/?q=','ViDEOs');" title="Search ViDEOs">ViDEOs</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="forWebSearch('http://www.wittysparks.com/searchvideos/?q=','TOPiCs');" title="Search TOPiCs">TOPiCs</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="forWebSearch('http://www.wittysparks.com/searchvideos/?q=','QUOTEs');" title="Search QUOTEs">QUOTEs</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
    </li>
</ul><input class="multisearchInput" name="q" type="text" value="Type here & press enter" onFocus="this.value=''"/></form>
```

What I am really after is a way of putting this **INSIDE** the input box, rather than the outside like is currently done in this example. I know it is possible because google does it here with its microphone icon:

https://www.google.com/search?q=test

My question is, what is the best way to achieve this, ideally with the most amount of compatibility and the least amount of code and hacking.

Comment: What you didnt check is google only gives the feel of it being inside input box. input box ends before microphone icon. zero borders are applied on the input. Container for input and mic icon has borders around it which makes it look like input contains mic.

Comment: How do they put the focus glow around the entire thing then? I thought this was impossible.

Comment: It's not a default browser input focus glow. One way to do it would be to set the border colour of the containing element in response to the focus event. Use your browser's debug tools (right-click then "Inspect Element", in Chrome) to have a look.

Comment: As @vishwanath says, it just has the appearance that it is inside the input

Comment: Using box shadow and other css thingies.

Comment: Ok, thank you all for clearing that up. Is this the better way to be doing this then, to put it outside and make it look like it is inside, rather than actually putting it inside? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/pnGve/

Comment: This is definitely one way of doing it. And since google is using it, you can trust them and rely on it for a while and save you cost of finding any better solution. They must have done it already.

Comment: @Jimmy what you have given is another solution. Putting right padding on the input box. This does look a better solution than what google is applying considering you wont have to rely of box shadow for focus.

Comment: I have a better solution than google?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the question to keep it simple for future references.

You can wrap your dropdown inside a container and change its border and other css on focus attained or removed.

Removed dropdown code and added containers for readability. All you need is formcontainer containing both the elements and event listeners.

```
<div id="formcontainer">
    <div id="dropdowncontainer">
        <!-- dropdown here-->
    </div>
    <div id="inputcontainer">
         <input class="multisearchInput" name="q" type="text" value="Type here & press enter" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And put this in your javascript code.

```
document.getElementById('multisearchInput').onfocus=function(){
    this.value='';
    document.getElementById('formcontainer').style['border'] ='1px solid red';
}

document.getElementById('multisearchInput').onblur=function(){
    document.getElementById('formcontainer').style['border'] ='none';
}
```

Running jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7BgYU/2/