# CSS: How to make dropdown in input box not overlap with long text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styling

I have a a dropdown menu inside my input box. When the text gets really long, the text and the drop down overlap. Using css, how can I make sure that no matter how long the text is, the drop down and text will never overlap?

Current Output:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

**HTML and css for input box:**

[image]

[image]

**HTML and CSS for the dropdown:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code to show how the dropdown is setup?

Comment: nice pictures, but if you want help show your html, css, unless you want a very general answer, like increase the z-index of "can edit" and set it;s background white

Comment: Looks like you could apply a `background-color` of `white` to the 'Can edit' element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert dropdown inside input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895506/insert-dropdown-inside-input-field)

Comment: @Trix, well we don't know for sure, unless we'll get to see the code, but IMHO he already has that kind of a solution and only needs a final touch with the css

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it helped you solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

As we don't know your code structure this is still a guesswork, but mostly you can achieve this by setting a `padding-right` value a bit higher than the width of the dropdown like this:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/6o6j00va/1/)

```css
.input-field {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right:100px; /* something like this */
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 300px;
}
.input-select{
  height:29px; color:skyblue; font-weight:bold; border:none; outline:none;
  margin-left:-95px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="input text">
<select class="input-select">
  <option value="">Google</option>
  <option value="">Yahoo</option>
  <option value="">Bing</option>
  <option value="">Wikipedia</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think putting a `margin-left:-95px;` for `select` will not work for every child `option` string length

Comment: Sure it wouldn't, but this is just for demo purposes, this why I had this "*setting a padding-right value a **bit higher than the width** of the dropdown*" in my answer. Thanks thought for mentioning that so the OP reads it twice

Comment: Also the dropdown might be positioned using `float` or `position:absolute` and not by negative `margin-left`, but the answer is about setting the "suitable" `padding-right` value

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css:

```
#can_edit {background-color: white;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
form{
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.parent{
  overflow: hidden;
}
input{
  width: 100%;
}
select{
  padding: 1px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select>
    <option>value 1</option>
    <option>value 2</option>
  </select>
  <div class="parent">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```